# Selenium connection time out when initializing driver

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I've written a Django (version 1.3, sadly) management command to connect to BrowserStack with Selenium and am going to be using to run integration tests. (I've had to write a custom management command to get around the fact that we use AskBot within this site and it messes up the Django testing framework in some funny ways; otherwise I would simply use the testing framework.)

Gist of the script is here https://gist.github.com/cellofellow/7491221. This is a port of an earlier script that just ran unittest directly without any Django context.

What happens is that when ran, I get a traceback like so:

```
./manage.py browserstack signup
Browser: IE
Browser Version: 10.0
Operating System: Windows
OS Version: 7

E
======================================================================
ERROR: runTest (apps.common.management.commands.browserstack.SignUpBasic)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jgardner/izeni/doterra_pro/apps/common/management/commands/browserstack.py", line 46, in setUp
    desired_capabilities=self.caps)
  File "/home/jgardner/.virtualenvs/doterra_pro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/jgardner/.virtualenvs/doterra_pro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 113, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/home/jgardner/.virtualenvs/doterra_pro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 162, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/jgardner/.virtualenvs/doterra_pro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 355, in execute
    return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
  File "/home/jgardner/.virtualenvs/doterra_pro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 402, in _request
    response = opener.open(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 897, in http_error_401
    url, req, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 872, in http_error_auth_reqed
    response = self.retry_http_basic_auth(host, req, realm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 885, in retry_http_basic_auth
    return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1187, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
timeout: timed out

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 5.201s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

In BrowserStack an instance is started but because whatever happens next can't connect, it simply runs for a minute or so and then exits.

The script it was ported from didn't have this problem. What may be causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I simply had to set `socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)` There are dozens of calls to `socket.setdefaulttimeout` in this codebase, both in dependencies and our own code, so who knows what it was actually set to.